# Visual studio 2010 loses mapping to TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have visual studio 2010 installed on user machines and TFS 2013 on server machine.I am facing a strange issue from few days. When I map any project to TFS team project it gets mapped perfectly. But when I open it again visual studio 2010 doesnot showing any mapping to the local folder on user system. That is it looses mapping to the project that is on local system and which was earlier mapped to that TFS team project. Any help will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share any screenshots for your issue?

Comment: How do you check it does not showing any mapping to the local folder? (e.g. can't check in/out)

Comment: It doesnot show any mapping to local folder so I am not able to load tfs project to the local project for which it was previously mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have selected the wrong workspace.

If the workspace changed, the mapping will definitely "lose".

- Mapped perfect with workspace PATRICK-W10

[image]

However, if the workspace changed to PATRICK-W10_1, you need to remap all files.

[image]

Please double check this.